# Jade Template - No images appear @ res.render()

Tags: node.js, pug

At x.jade (example file) with this line:

```
img(id='add-razaoSocial', class='input-img', src='images/add-mono.png')
```

From index.jade, if i do:

```
res.redirect('my/path/way')
```

It's ok, if i do:

```
res.render('x')
```

the img don't appear. See this link ( http://cl.ly/2u1A2P0P1b2b3F0b0Q2v ) with image ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing useful in that image you've shown us. Most probably your picture has a bad relative path or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your javascript-files are also 404 - not found, there seems to be another problem.

You basically do a redirect after something happened, like an update, login or whatever, and all redirects go back to a route where something is rendered. So, you don't redirect from .jade but from app.js.

Can you provide some more information and source code of your routes?

Answer (score 2):

Use src='/images/add-mono.png' instead of src='images/add-mono.png'